# use of tcpdf checkpagebreak() results in invalid pdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

If I want to check wether the page will break ater 30mm, how do I do this?
According to the documentation I think it goes something like this:

$pdf->checkPageBreak(30, '', true);
(http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a9e8e4b4d75485b8f1e3aa2133a811e50)

It's not working though. Do you know what I am doing wrong, or do you know of a better documentation/tutorial for tcpdf in general?

p.s. I have tried it with and without setAutoPageBreak();